# Help with choosing a probability distribution to model existing dataset

Tags: probability-distributions

I would appreciate your help with this.

I have a large dataset with one variable 'days', with range 1.5 days to 23 days. Possible values are separated by 0.5 days, so the dataset only has 46 possible values. Am i right to assume that this data is discrete?

I've been asked to model this data using a probability distribution but am struggling to understand which one to choose to model it, and then how to calculate the parameters associated with it. The histogram is skewed to the left greatly, as most values are between 1.5 and 3.5 days, declining sharply after this to 23 days.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What process (experiment, measurements...) has created the data? The process will inform how best to model it, not the data. It is discrete data, maybe Poisson with a mean of 2 or so.

Comment: What does a histogram suggest?